# Issues setting up DMA doublebuffer mode to work with SPI rx only on STM32

Tags: c, stm32, spi, dma

I'm attempting to create a data logger that intakes data from a sensor node with three modalities and transmits that data using three different SPI busses to a Nucleo-f746zg.  I would then like to use DMA peripheral to memory mode to take the incoming data from each bus and put it into one of three buffers that will eventually get written to a USB flash drive using FATFS.  I'm having issues initializing the DMA in double buffer mode.  When I look at each register it seems to be configured correctly but none of the interrupts fire and the data transfer doesn't occur.

I know that the SPI data is coming in.  I initially tried this using interrupts but the data rate was too fast and I was losing data so I pivoted to DMA.  The Data, once it's in the register correctly writes to the USB drive as well.  I'm using the "LL" drivers for both SPI and DMA.

This is my current DMA initialization code:

```
uint16_t TEST_BUFFER_0[10000];
uint16_t TEST_BUFFER_1[10000];

LL_DMA_SetChannelSelection(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_0);

LL_DMA_SetDataTransferDirection(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);

LL_DMA_EnableDoubleBufferMode(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3);

LL_DMA_SetPeriphIncMode(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_PERIPH_NOINCREMENT);

LL_DMA_SetMemoryIncMode(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_MEMORY_INCREMENT);

LL_DMA_SetPeriphSize(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD);

LL_DMA_SetMemorySize(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD);

LL_DMA_DisableFifoMode(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3);

LL_DMA_SetMemoryAddress(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3,TEST_BUFFER_1);

LL_DMA_SetMemory1Address(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, TEST_BUFFER_0);

LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, 10000);

LL_DMA_SetPeriphAddress(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_SPI_DMA_GetRegAddr(SPI2));

LL_DMA_EnableIT_HT(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3);

LL_DMA_EnableIT_TC(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3);

LL_DMA_EnableStream(DMA1,LL_DMA_STREAM_3);

LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI2);

LL_SPI_Enable(SPI2);
```

I'm not seeing either of the interrupts firing nor am I seeing my buffers get full.  I'm not one hundred percent sure what actually initiates the DMA transfer other than the documentation alluding to this occurring automatically when data comes in.  I'm kind of stuck at this point and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: I would recommend starting with HAL drivers to understand, then optimize if needed using LL approach. Is SPI2 the only peripheral using DMA? If not, is another peripheral already using the allocated DMA resource.

Comment: SPI 2 is just the one I'm starting with.  It's the bus with the highest activity but once I've got it working there I'll be using SPI1 and 3 as well.  I didn't use the HAL drivers because, from what I've read, they don't support doublebuffer mode.  I'll try setting it up with HAL though see if it actually works.